# A High-Quality Puzzle

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, music, video-games

Taking a break from cryptic-clues/crosswords puzzles, this simple puzzle has a couple of firsts for me. Given the following songs from video games, find the name of someone who's a fan of anagrams.

[Full Force Forward - Payday 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4V0SCd9eGs)
[Encounter - Metal Gear Solid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_ca6akbGXQ)
[Sea Bottom Segue - Sonic Lost World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TDJMwTNv0w)
[K.K. Cruisin' - Animal Crossing: City Folk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dA84QYVEbAI)
[Danger Mystery - Undertale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dY1ZBGNJuaA)
[Ringside - Rhythm Heaven Fever](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsXWEVoiugI)
[POP/STARS - League of Legends](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qU7dqywqwWQ)
[Faceless Disco Dance - Paper Mario: The Origami King](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0YrOj0rzEg)
[Golf - Course Select - Wii Sports](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3AYVGst32I)
[Boomer Kuwanger Stage - Mega Man X](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arv0ZJQ1pKg)
[Semi-Charmed Life - Rock Band 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0S2C2aETcY)

Hint:

> If you wanna go by appearances, the fifth song could be "[Amadeus (Opening) - Steins;Gate 0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjD4smtV-o4)".

Hint 2:

> This puzzle is entirely solvable with no video game knowledge; just the songs themselves are sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> **SILVAGUNNER.**

First, we see that every video linked here is

> by **SilvaGunner,** a parody channel who makes "rips" of video game songs that are secretly remixes and other songs in disguise. (https://siivagunner.fandom.com/wiki/SiIvaGunner)

The person who is a fan of anagrams, therefore, is

> **SilvaGunner** themself, as they have also gone by the anagram **GilvaSunner**, which is the video game ripping channel they parody. (https://siivagunner.fandom.com/wiki/GilvaSunner)

This also reveals that the title is a reference to

> SilvaGunner's running joke that he only makes "high quality" rips. ("I only upload high quality video game rips.")

However, I think maybe there is more to this puzzle, as evidenced by Hint #1, so I'm going to go down the list of songs, because

> each of the songs is secretly a remix of a different song.

> 1. Full Force Forward - Payday 2
>  **Never Gonna Give You Up** by Rick Astley
>  
>  2. Encounter - Metal Gear Solid
>  **El Sonidito** by Hechizeros Band
>  
>  3. Sea Bottom Segue - Sonic Lost World
>  **Snow halation** from Love Live!
>  
>  4. K.K. Cruisin' - Animal Crossing: City Folk
>  **Virtual Insanity** by Jamiroquai
>  
>  5. Danger Mystery - Undertale
>  **Giorno's Theme/Il Vento D'Oro** from Jojo's Bizarre Adventure: Golden Wind
>  
>  6. Ringside - Rhythm Heaven Fever
>  **Uptown Funk** by Mark Ronson & Bruno Mars
>  
>  7. POP/STARS - League of Legends
>  **Gentleman** and **Gangnam Style** by PSY
>  
>  8. Faceless Disco Dance - Paper Mario: The Origami King
>  **Replay** by Lady Gaga
>  
>  9. Golf - Course Select - Wii Sports
>  **I Want It That Way** by the Backstreet Boys
>  
>  10. Boomer Kuwanger Stage - Mega Man X
>  **Never Gonna Give You Up** by Rick Astley
>  
>  11. Semi-Charmed Life - Rock Band 3
>  **All Star** by Smash Mouth

And from Hint #1:

> Amadeus (Opening) - Steins;Gate 0 ("the fifth song, if you want to go by appearances")
>  **Lose Yourself** by Eminem

The first letters of all these hidden songs forms:

> **SILVAGUNNER.**

Comment: Hint #1 is there because rot13(FvVinThaare vf fcryyrq jvgu n hccrepnfr v gung ybbxf yvxr na y), but you got it!

Comment: Ahhh, that's why I got tripped up the first time :) makes sense now.